# URL rewriting in asp.net 2.0

Tags: url-rewriting, asp.net-2.0

I am using asp.net 2.0 with C#. My Querystring is like this

www.xyz.com\default.aspx?name=steve

I want it to be like "www.xyz.com\name\steve\default.aspx" or www.xyz.com\FakeName\name\steve\default.aspx

I have found that I can achieve this by URL rewritting but the explanation I found of net is too complex for me, also on the other page_load I have to get the value of Name.

after rewritting how would I get the name.

Answer (score 0):

While you could probably solve this with several regular expressions and URL rewriting, I think it might be easier to use [ASP.NET routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx) instead.  It will do exactly what you want.